# Issue of the default parameter in class

Tags: c++, class, parameters, default

I have a question about default parameter in *C++* class:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Test {
    public :
        Test(int ai = 0, int bi = 0)
            : a(ai), b(bi) { }
        void print() { printf("a = %d, b = %d", a, b); };
    private :
        int a, b;       
};

int main() {
    Test t(1);
    t.print();  
    return 0;
}
```

In this code,

result will be "a = 1 , b = 0(default parameter)"

If I want to set "a" is default parameter and "b" is other value, how should I write the code?
Is there any way to solve this question?

Comment: You cannot 'skip' a parameter in a function call.  Default parameters only pick up with the first not-provided parameter.  So you can't pass in a value for `b`, while letting `a` be the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, you may omit function arguments that are declared with default parameters, but you can only omit one or more function arguments from the *end* of the argument list. So, given

```
Test(int ai = 0, int bi = 0)
```

there is no way to pass a value for `bi` and leave `ai` as the default value.